# How to use different security.yml files / security settings?

Tags: security, configuration, kernel, symfony, sonata

I have Symfony3 project where I want completly separate Sonata admin bundles from main appliaction. Main application and sonata users are different entities which are never cross. Also all security settings are independent and different. Furthermore in future there will be another admin subsytem - completly different from current one for another aspect of application.

I think about different environments or overriding kernel (by [this](https://mihai-stancu.ro/2015/10/03/multiple-apps-in-one-repo-with-symfony2/) methodics) and need to know how to specify security settings per environment (if it is correct approach and won't blow up framwork) or make it selectable by overriding kernel. Or... whatever approach you know to do this.

My Symfony version is 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new environments in addition to the existing `prod`, `dev` and `test` ones, as described in the documentation [How to Master and Create new Environments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html). This will give you access to a new configuration file (`config_[your_new_environment].yml`), which in turn could load a different `security.yml` file altogether in the `imports` statement and override the default values.

Example:

```
// config_sonata.yml

imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: security_sonata.yml }
```

In your case though, I would first investigate using different firewalls as part of the main `security.yml` file. If the URLs you wish to secure in your different applications do not overlap, you can simply [add more firewalls](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html) and [user providers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html). This should allow you to cover all your needs and keep everything in one place.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually my fail that I missed import security.yml statement in config file and thought it is loaded in different way. So I will use one security.yml while possible and it seems easy to separate them if it will be necessary. I assume using differnent security settings per enviroment is correct and supported approach. Btw did you ever configured project with different security settings? Are there any problems with this in your experience?

Comment: No I never had to use per-environment security files. Since I never have overlapping URLs, everything can be taken care of in the standard security file. If it did happen though, I think I would create different applications altogether. And if there was code to be shared between those applications, I would place it all in a bundle.

I think the main issue with multiple environments is that it's not very standard. You know why you did it, but it won't be obvious to a new developer jumping onto the project down the road.

Comment: Well, I hope it will work.. Separation of environments has obvious reason like loading sonata bundles in kernel only for admin section, and complex configs and security settings needed to handle two admin backends plus main application.